# increment a value in an array if a match is found

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

so i've got the following array

```json
// movie.json
// example output (beautified) from: /createvote movie#1,movie#2,movie#3,movie#4
[
  {
    "label": "movie#1",
    "value": "movie#1",
    "voteCount": 0
  },
  {
    "label": "movie#2",
    "value": "movie#2",
    "voteCount": 0
  },
  {
    "label": "movie#3",
    "value": "movie#3",
    "voteCount": 0
  },
  {
    "label": "movie#4",
    "value": "movie#4",
    "voteCount": 0
  }
]
```

created using

```js
movieListArr.map(x => ({label: x, value: x, voteCount: 0}));
    fs.writeFile("movie.json", JSON.stringify( labelArr ), (err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
           console.log("writeFile sucess:");
           console.log(fs.readFileSync("movie.json", "utf8"));
        }
    });
```

and with the following I'm trying to compare it to

```js
interaction.values[0]; // example output: movie#3
```

that gives me what a person has voted.

what I'm trying to do is if a user votes something ex: `movie#3` I want to look through `movie.json` and increment voteCount by one for `movie#3`. I've tried searching for a solution already and honestly, I can't seem to put my finger on it. If there's a better solution to doing this instead of through `.json` files I'm all ears too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the item in the array whose `value` property is `'movie#3'`, then increment it's `voteCount` property.

```js
const movies=[{label:"movie#1",value:"movie#1",voteCount:0},{label:"movie#2",value:"movie#2",voteCount:0},{label:"movie#3",value:"movie#3",voteCount:0},{label:"movie#4",value:"movie#4",voteCount:0}];

const choice = 'movie#3'

function vote(movieList, vote){
  movieList.find(e => e.value == vote).voteCount++;
}

vote(movies, choice)

console.log(movies)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thank you very much.

Comment: @justsurvivinglol if this answer solved your problem give it a checkmark !

Answer (score 1):

You could find the object and increment the count.

```
const movie = movies.find(( label ) => label === selectd);

if (movie) ++movie.voteCount;
```

Comment: just what i needed very much appreciated